# OpsHub Visual Studio Online recovering deleted files

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I have just migrated a project from TFS2012 into Visual Studio Online using OpsHub and I'm not sure why or how but it has recovered deleted files.  These files weren't present on TFS2012 as they were deleted a few years ago and they are now present within Visual Studio Online.  Is this because of the history or should this have even happened?

Thanks

Comment: Most likely a Merge operation performed did not yield an expected outcome of change types. Can you please share the log files to ovsmu@opshub.com and we'll verify what the issue was.

Comment: What part of the log files would you like as the logs folder totals 2.91GB

Comment: Since we are not yet at the root cause, I am afraid we'll need all of them. If you zip them, the size would drastically reduce, after which, if feasible, then you can upload to a cloud host (like skydrive or dropbox) and share the link with us through mail.