# OpsHub migration resulted in deleted file being recovered

Tags: opshub, azure-devops

We had performed the migration of our whole repository from TFS to VSTS using OpsHub.  It seemed to go ok except for some projects that it just couldn't handle.  Everything looked ok, until developers were going into projects and find all the files that had been deleted from the projects.  This has left all the projects and folders a mess.  If you look in the history of those projects you can see the actual deletes in the changesets reflected by the file being displayed with a strike-through going over name.  But looking in the folders the files are there.  If this was an existing issue, was it part of some disclaimer that we missed?

Is there any way to cause those deletes to occur?  We don't want to have to migrate everything again because it took weeks to get everything migrated before.  I just need to find out if there are any other options.

Comment: Same issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32964935/opshub-visual-studio-online-recovering-deleted-files

Comment: Can you send us the logs located at C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility\logs to ovsmu@opshub.com. The root cause might possibly be different, we'll have to analyze it first.

Comment: I have sent our logs.

Comment: We've had the same thing happen with a project that was originally created in TFS 2008. There seems to be a bug in OpsHub that doesn't deal with projects created back then which have source control history that is no longer possible since the introduction of TFS 2010.